# Show that the number of square roots of 1 in a Field, F, is exactly 2

Tags: abstract-algebra

So for this I am given that a Field, $F$, has size $q$ where $q$ is odd, ie $F_q$. I'm also told that the group of units of any finite field is cyclic. So my thinking at this point is that the number of units is $(q-1)$ which is obviously even.

Now at this point I am taking the set of units $(F_q)^x$ and calling it $U$. As $U$ is cyclic then $U^{q-1}$ = $1$.

Now I can say that $U^\frac{q-1}{2}$ has order $2$

Also as $F$ is a field we know that it has at most 2 square roots for 1 by $a^2 - 1 = 0$

But I don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler than that: in any field, a quadratic polynomial has at most two roots (and more generally, a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots). Can you find two roots for $X^2-1$?

Comment: Yeah thanks, like I understand this because this is actually the answer to an earlier part. But the question wants me to show there is strictly 2 square roots. If you look at my comment below it outlines the question

Comment: If you find two, you'll know there are exactly two. For this polynomial, it shouldn't be too hard…

Comment: I don't think you're quite reading what I'm putting. If you looks below I comment on a reply with the full question. The part I am stuck on is part d) I think there's much more to it than X^2-1=0. Actually  
puu.sh/vUlky/f4a43efae3.png here

Answer (score 0):

In an integral domain, $1$ and $-1$ are the only roots of $1$. The whole point is that $-1\neq 1$ when the integral domain has a characteristic non-equal to $2$.

If you want to stick to the exercise, here is another approach:

As reminded $F^\times$ is cyclic of order $q-1$ which is even, namely $2\vert(q-1)$. Therefore, there exists an element of order $2$ in $F^\times$. This element is precisely a root of $1$ which is distinct from $1$ and there is at least $2$ distinct roots of $1$ in $F$. On the other hand, there is at most $2$ roots of $1$ in $F$, since they are roots of a quadratic polynomial, $X^2-1$.

Comment: See the part I don't really understand is that the question tells me that the group of units of a finite field is cyclic. What relevance does that have?

Comment: While this is indeed true, I do not really see the link with the roots of $1$. Is there any other question in the exercise?

Comment: http://puu.sh/vUlky/f4a43efae3.png is the complete question

Answer (score 0):

For all element $x \neq 0$ of your field, we have $x^{q-1}=1$. $q-1$ is even.The polynomial$ X^{\frac{q-1}{2}}-1$ has at most $\frac{q-1}{2}$ roots. So in particular there is some $y$ such that $z=y^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \neq 1$. And $z^2=1$.