# In a general field, is it always true that if x * x = 1 then x = 1 or x = (-1)?

Tags: field-theory

So in an arbitrary field where we call the multiplicative identity "1":

1 * 1 = 1 by definition, and (-1) * (-1) = 1 because you can prove that double negatives cancel, but can any other square roots of 1 exist?

It feels to me like they probably can't, but I'm having a hard time actually proving why that has to be true.  This is equivalent to the question of whether the equation

x = reciprocal (x)

has any solutions besides 1 and (-1), but that also feels like it doesn't without being able to see an obvious proof.

Comment: Hint: $x^2=1$ is equivalent to $0=x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2287109/42969.

Comment: In a field, no polynomial of degree $d$ can have more than $d$ roots.

Comment: @leoli1 That was enough of a hint for me to see how you do the proof.  TY TY.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If $x^2 = 1$, then $x^2 - 1 = 0$, so $(x + 1)(x - 1) = 0$. Because fields are integral domains, either $x + 1 = 0$ or $x - 1 = 0$, and the question is solved as you claim. This is a specific instance of lulu's comment that fields can have at most $d$ solutions to a polynomial of degree $d$.